# PhotonPan2 Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Кто-нибудь знает как воспользоваться Photon Pan2 Instantiate так, чтобы для первого пользователя префабы спавнило в одном месте, для другого пользователя префабы в другом месте. Для примера онлайн покер, Пользователь появляется посередине, а все остальные по кругу (для него), для другого пользователя он посередине, но остальные по кругу, буду рад вашей помощи

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Например -- спавни в локацию относительно камеры каждого игрока если это карты в покере

Comment: В случае онлайн покера - спавни карты в локацию относительно камеры каждого игрока. Сервер дает 2 карты,  а клиент размещает относительно своей камеры и говорит серверу о выбранной локации карт. Или же "захардкодить" - каждое отдельное место относительно каждого стульчика -- разместить пустой обьект который и будет показывать где спавнить карты - для каждого отдельного игрока)